# Thumbnails break for no reason

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

Sometimes when I'm using my pc normally, I get broken thumbnails and explorer just going crazy and heck it's not the "go to folder options" thing, It's the THUMBNAIL NOT LOADING BECAUSE SOMETHING IS CORRUPTED.

Restarting does fix it but it comes back after a couple of hours, used to be days or even weeks.
Yes, I did try clearing my cache and tried many different tutorials heck I even tried this:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

and it kind of did work but still, I'm getting the same thing after a couple of days and there's no permanent fix for it.
Also sometimes I can't delete some files I downloaded or created and it either takes me a couple of minutes so I can download that file or I have to restart my PC just to delete a single file.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: It's not a hard drive failure, also it's installed on an SSD